# Pyinstaller: Create single shell script in linux

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Can we create single shell script using pyinstaller just like we create single exe in windows from python script using `pyinstaller --onefile`

Comment: Nope. You can't.

Answer (score 1):

Nope you can't do that.

But, you can use this: https://github.com/ZYunH/Python-script-converter

It converts .py to .command executable on mac or linux